# "gets stdin" is not waiting for user input and exits

Tags: tcl, user-input, stdin

I am working on some TCL script where i want the user to enter his choice from the given list of OPTIONS.

I am using "gets stdin" for the user input.
But my opened terminal is not waiting for user input and just exists.

Input →   `gets stdin abc`
Output →  `-1`

Comment: What platform is this? Is it in wish on Windows?

Comment: It is terminal on Linux

Answer (score 1):

The -1 indicates that either EOF was reached on stdin, or that your stdin is in non-blocking mode. You can check by running `eof stdin` and `fconfigure stdin -blocking`. On a normal terminal those commands should return 0 and 1 respectively.

To set stdin to blocking mode, you can use `fconfigure stdin -blocking 1`

Comment: In my case , output for both eof stdin and fconfigure stdin -blocking is 1. 
Even i tried setting stdin to blocking mode but no luck with it as well.

Comment: Setting the channel to blocking does not cancel an EOF condition. Now the question is why do you have an EOF condition on stdin. Did you perform any redirections when you call the script, or run it as part of a pipeline? In other words, show exactly how you run the script.

Comment: I have this ctat tool which spawn a tcl 8.4 terminal and there i am executing both the commands.

Comment: Then apparently that ctat tool is using some kind of custom in- and output to its terminal and doesn't use stdin (and stdout). You will have to ask the creators of the tool how to get a line of user input.

Comment: For stdout , when i have executed "eof stdout" it gave the output as 0. In case of "eof stdin" , the output was 1.   Probably i have to ask the creators of this ctat tool now. Thanks for your help Schelte.